# NSDictionary not properly storing CGRect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I seem to be having problems storing a `CGRect` into an `NSDictionary`. The code I'm using:

```
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Crocodile", [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(100,100,200,200)], nil];
```

From what I've read, that should wrap my `CGRect` up into an `NSValue` and store it into the dictionary.

However, when I tried to `NSLog` it, the value returns as {{0,0}, {0,0}}

```
NSLog(@"Crocodile value is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect([[dictionary objectForKey:@"Crocodile"] CGRectValue]));
```

I have checked my dictionary count and the items seem to be inserted. I'm not sure where this is failing. I've also tried to manually break it down by creating a `CGRect` var, then an `NSValue` var, and sticking that into the dictionary with the same results.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The order of arguments should be (object, key, object, key, …), so in your code the object is `@"Crocodile"` and the key is the rect.

Swap them and it should work:

```
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(100,100,200,200)], // object first…
    @"Crocodile", // …then key
    nil];
```

---

Note that keys aren't required to be instances of NSString, they can be any instance of a class conforming to NSCopying.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I was following these examples:
http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000010.php

Comment: @user339946 I would contact the author of that article and tell him/her that the code is wrong.

Comment: Ah, to be fair, the article was published in 2001. :/

Comment: @user339946 that doesn't make it OK. The method hasn't changed since Mac OS X v10.0.

Answer (score 10):

You can store it as NSString -

```
        NSStringFromCGRect(<#CGRect rect#>)
```

And then recover with

```
         CGRectFromString(<#NSString *string#>)
```

Good Luck

Comment: +1 Was helpful for collecting animation data into an NSDictionary.